# Android: How can you "unpack" or "dump" files from a library project into the main project?

Tags: java, android

I would like to "dump" or "unpack" a library project's files into the main project, which would let me customize the library's contents for that project. Is that possible, and what is a way to do so? Can I just copy the entire library project's src/, res/, and manifest file into the libs/ folder of the main project?

(Please note that I do not want to touch the files from the original library project because I have other projects that are using it.)

Comment: Are you sure it's impossible to modify the library via the usual OO methods of composition and inheritance?

Comment: Great idea. I just learned about sub classes this week. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your library is a `.jar` containing `.java` source files, then you can unpack it using, eg. unzip, and move the contents of its src and res directories into *your project's src and res directories*.

If, however, this library contains only compiled Java `.class` files, there's not much you will be able to do with them. Unless you want to try to decompile them, the library must be used as-is.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip savanto

Answer (score 1):

I think that is better change the project name of the library and make a copy of this. This allow you to modify the files and dont mix it with your actual project.